# Reshape dataframe from vertical to horizontal based on multiple columns in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Given a toy data as follows:

```
                                     id group_name   v1  v2
0  C45C6DA8-0721-40F3-B5CE-CA72DE102707       a_13  110  70
1  74D067B1-819B-4E9A-A1A7-2CD2E70577A9        a_0  118  76
2  65376D7B-8816-4FA0-9A2D-401D15808F92       b_39  130  80
3  CABB6BFA-98A8-417F-B765-D9C2C69511FC       a_15  125  75
4  43D115F4-AA1F-4241-9AE0-2947986D9ED0       a_13  130  75
```

I need to groupby `id` and `group_name`, then reshape dataframe from vertical to horizontal, please note that new columns name are renamed based on the value after `_` in the `group_name` column.

```
                                     id group_name   v1_0  v2_0  v1_13  v2_13  v1_15  v2_15  v1_39  v2_39
0  C45C6DA8-0721-40F3-B5CE-CA72DE102707       a_13    NaN   NaN  110.0   70.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
1  74D067B1-819B-4E9A-A1A7-2CD2E70577A9        a_0  118.0  76.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
2  65376D7B-8816-4FA0-9A2D-401D15808F92       b_39    NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN  130.0   80.0
3  CABB6BFA-98A8-417F-B765-D9C2C69511FC       a_15    NaN   NaN    NaN    NaN  125.0   75.0    NaN    NaN
4  43D115F4-AA1F-4241-9AE0-2947986D9ED0       a_13    NaN   NaN  130.0   75.0    NaN    NaN    NaN    NaN
```

How could I do that in Pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this can be done with pivot table with some addtional work:

```
out = (df.pivot_table(index = ['id', 'group_name'],
                columns = df['group_name'].str.split('_').str[1])
                # columns = df['group_name'].str.extract('(\d+)',expand=False)
                .sort_index(level = 1, axis = 1))
out.columns = out.columns.map('{0[0]}_{0[1]}'.format)
out = out.reset_index()
display(out)
```

---

[image]

Comment: I get an `ValueError: a CategoricalDtype must be passed to perform an update, got CategoricalDtype(categories=['00BF4A0B-E3C3-4B30-A4DE-55CAF927EFE6', '00D65ECC-7AD3-43E8-ACD4-60B8084E0990', 'FFD74827-669D-4185-A5AA-529644AF397F'], ordered=False)` with real data.

Comment: @ahbon I am unable to replicate this error, works for me with your data sample with dtype category. Is the error because of the transformation are from something that you are trying to update..?

Comment: In stead of using `str.split('_').str[1]`, could we use extract `number` from `string`method? Because in real data, it likes `groupA26weeks, groupB13weeks`, something like that.

Comment: @ahbon yes try `str.extract('(\d+)',expand=False)` may be..?

Comment: Great, `out.columns` seems not including `id` and `group_name`? Sorry, i'm not able to see the plot you have put because of internet issue.

Comment: yes correct , they are index, you can `reset_index()` later to view them as columns. `out.columns` step is merging the merging the multiindex hence it is better to keep the id and group_number as index,  we can reset as needed @ahbon

Comment: I'm not able to `print(out)` directly, but after `dat = out.reset_index()`, I can `print(dat)`.

Comment: One more question, I notice you have used `group_name` as `index` and column name at same time?

Comment: @ahbon because we wanted the numbers from group name and pivot at the same time retain as a column. Did I get your question incorrectly?

Comment: If you get same result as in the question, it’s ok

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you should you `pandas.melt` function, as described in documentation. https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html

```
df.columns = [list('ABC'), list('DEF')]
df
   A  B  C
   D  E  F
0  a  1  2
1  b  3  4
2  c  5  6
pd.melt(df, col_level=0, id_vars=['A'], value_vars=['B'])
   A variable  value
0  a        B      1
1  b        B      3
2  c        B      5
pd.melt(df, id_vars=[('A', 'D')], value_vars=[('B', 'E')])
  (A, D) variable_0 variable_1  value
0      a          B          E      1
1      b          B          E      3
2      c          B          E      5
```